# How do you see values when debugging in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, sparrow-framework

I'm trying to see what the value of myImage.height is in the debug mode in Xcode, I've got a breakpoint on this line...

```
float s=myImage.height/cos(30*M_PI/180)/2;
```

It all runs fine and get's to that line, in the debug panel I can see myImage (my Image is a Sparrow framework SPImage object) but I can't see any values for any of the class vars.

This is literally the first time I've used a break point/debug panel in xcode so I'm probably just not doing something right.

I also tried

```
NSLog(@"myImage height: %f",myImage.height);
```

But I can't see that being outputted in the output panel either.

I'm coming from a AS3 background, where you would see...

myImage.height along with it's value to the right in the debug panel in Flash, so I'm looking for the same thing in Xcode. Do I have to run it in a different mode or is there another panel to open or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the console area, you can show 2 distinct "parts", one is the variables in scope, and the other is the actual output console. In the stack area, you can see all variables in scope.

You can also hover your mouse over any variable *in code*, then click on the little disclosuer arrow and select "print description" to have it plop it into the console. (The console is also where NSLog stuff goes).

Check out this picture:

[image: Xcode debugging]

And then this one: 
[image]

Note you can also "print description" from the variable area:

[image: print description from variables area]

**edit** here's more detail on the hover-access to the value: Click on the variable name, then move the mouse to the right, and there should pop up a yellow bar with info about the instance. This is is different from the little blue arrow, which is available even when not debugging.

[image: hover access to runtime value]
[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you can type directly into the console i.e. `po items` would print the `description` method of the items object. To see raw values (i.e. int, CGRect etc) use `p myRect`.

Comment: Cool, thanks that's useful. I did that though, and there's no values for anything, I'm using this line above the one I posted
myImage = [[SPImage alloc] initWithTexture:[Media atlasTexture:iName]];
so maybe it takes time for values to show up when you setup an object??

Comment: If your breakpoint is on that line, then you are correct, it's not initialized yet. Just step to the next line.

Comment: And when you print the description, it does not print anything?

Comment: I couldn't get the print description to appear in-code, the little down arrow just had 2 options, one was for edit all in scope, but I managed to get print description to come up in the debug panel, and for that in the output it came up with nil for the myImage object, which I don't get, because the code runs fine meaning the object must be created at that point.

Comment: If it says it's nil, then it's nil; but that might hint that either you are breaking too early, somehow printing the description of the wrong thing, or there is something else going on.

Comment: also, I added clarification on accessing the debugging hover tooltip thingy.

Answer (score 0):

If anything is being outputted, it's in the bottom panel. There are three icons on the top right of the bottom panel, and each one shows different data views. Try all three. In case you can't see the bottom panel, you can show it with the middle button in the segmented control above the word "View" in the top right of your XCode window.